# Determining statistical significance of data changing over time

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have collected motion data from three people over two days. Each of the subjects collected motion data from themselves for around 5 hours a day, for the two days, so I have about 10 hours of data in total per person. So far I've done two things:

1. I've averaged the two days, per person, together to get one data set per person which represents their motion over time.
2. I've applied a line of best fit to this single data set per person, and then calculated the percentage change from start to finish using this line (see below).

[image]

From the image I've calculated a 138% change over the averaged trial of one subject. However, I've been asked to determine if this is **statistically significant** and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Ideally I want to calculate the significance of change per person, as opposed to against each other, but if I could also calculate the significance between them that would be good too. Would I also want to determine the significance between their two day collection?

I have access to an array of statistical tools, MATLAB, Excel, and SPSS. If someone could help me work this out it would be most appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use time series methods. That should be doable in MATLAB, although 'how to... in MATLAB' is off-topic here. Someone who is an expert in TS will be able to explain the ideas for you, & then you may need to search for a MATLAB TS tutorial to implement them.